# 'unused argument' error in read_csv, check.names = FALSE

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a dataset with duplicate column names, and I don't want them renamed with suffixes when loading the file (right now `R` appends a `.x` on the duplicate columns). I've read quite a few posts that say to include `check.names = FALSE` command, but when I do I get an 'unused argument `(check.names = FALSE)`' error. Here's the code:

```
master.ds <- read_csv("name.csv", check.names = FALSE)
qualtrics.wide <- data.frame(master.ds)
```

Thoughts would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: `check.names` is an argument for the function `read.csv`, not `read_csv`

Comment: Please have a look at the help files `?read_csv` and `?read.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no argument `check.names` for `read_csv`. Assuming you're actually using `readr`, see the reference: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf.

But more likely, you're trying to use `read.csv`.